# JQuery: использовать ToggleClass чтобы свернуть неактивные элементы меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

Имеем следующий скрипт, который сворачивает и разворачивает элементы меню по нажатию на конкретный пункт меню. При этом, при нажатии на `class="click"` с целью открыть. остальные пункты остаются открытыми, если были открыты ранее. Как сделать, чтобы остальные пункты сворачивались?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".top_tr")
      .nextUntil(".top_tr", ".tr_elem")
      .toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tamalaks.ru/ldck_styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tamalaks.ru/ldck_styles/from_old.css">
<table class="table_preiskurant green">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:59%;" class="f_tf">
        <div class="th_block">Name</div>
      </th>
      <th class="l_tf">
        <div class="th_block pr_t_nw">Price</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="th_block">
          <span class="sale" style="margin:0 auto;">Info</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="th_block">
          <span class="sale" style="margin:0 auto;">Info</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 1</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">1 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">3 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click">
        <strong>Block 2</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
    1 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
    2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">3 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 3</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">1 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">3 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 4</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
   Element 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">7 500 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">6 375 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">6 000 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        element 2
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">6 500 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">5 525 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">5 200 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
   element 3</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">6 000 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">5 100 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">4 800 руб.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Исключение из найденных элементов .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").click(function() {
  $(".top_tr, .tr_elem").not($(this).closest(".top_tr").nextUntil(".top_tr", ".tr_elem")).removeClass("open");
    $(this).closest(".top_tr")
      .nextUntil(".top_tr", ".tr_elem")
      .toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tamalaks.ru/ldck_styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tamalaks.ru/ldck_styles/from_old.css">
<table class="table_preiskurant green">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:59%;" class="f_tf">
        <div class="th_block">Name</div>
      </th>
      <th class="l_tf">
        <div class="th_block pr_t_nw">Price</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="th_block">
          <span class="sale" style="margin:0 auto;">Info</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="th_block">
          <span class="sale" style="margin:0 auto;">Info</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 1</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">1 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem open">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">3 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click">
        <strong>Block 2</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
    1 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
    2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">3 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 3</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">1 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">2 element</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">3 element</td>
      <td class="t-price__price">1</td>
      <td class="light_blue">2</td>
      <td class="red">3</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="top_tr tr_ctrl">
      <td colspan="5" class="click"><strong>Block 4</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
   Element 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">7 500 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">6 375 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">6 000 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        element 2
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">6 500 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">5 525 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">5 200 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_elem">
      <td class="t-price__title">
        <a href="">
   element 3</a>
      </td>
      <td class="t-price__price">6 000 руб.</td>
      <td class="light_blue">5 100 руб.</td>
      <td class="red">4 800 руб.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: моё будет тем же решением,  лови плюс )

Comment: Супер! а можно сюда добавить slideToggle для медленной анимации раскрытия?

Comment: @theblackpost конечно, только текущие стили нужно пересмотреть, т.к. эффект `slideToggle` с `td.table-cell` будет не таким как ожидается (не будет плавного скрытия/разворачивания).